# How to use Session variables asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I cant seem to pass my variable through to the next page. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
var finalValue = value * sqlCouponValue;
finalValue = Math.Round(finalValue, 2);
Session["discountedOrderTotal"] = finalValue.ToString();
```

where i am trying to call it again on the next page:

```
e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "$" + Session["discountOrderTotal"];
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I have never used session variables before and am not sure why it is just returning a `$`. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's going wrong? Is there an error? Perhaps you need a cast, i.e.: `"$" + (string)Session["discountOrderTotal"]`

Comment: You might want to take a look at using [facade](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16656/Manage-ASP-NET-Session-Variables-using-the-Facad) to help avoid this and other issues with Session state management

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have different names.  discountedOrderTotal vs discountOrderTotal

Comment: happens to the best of us

Comment: i prefer to persist a class object to a session variable, that way i can utilize strongly typed properties.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes. Make sure you're taking regular breaks, even if its just 5 minutes every 15-20 or so to refocus your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should be careful is the name of the session. It should be same and when you are retrieving the session then you need to specify the type because it returns an object. So try this when you call this to next page

```
e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "$" + Session["discountedOrderTotal"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>Transfer Request ID</asp:TableCell>
                           <asp:TableCell>  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TransferRequestId") %>'></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
                           <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
             <asp:TableCell>Employee Name</asp:TableCell>
                           <asp:TableCell>  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeName") %>'></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
                           <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Value="APPROVE" Text="Approve" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button></asp:TableCell>

            <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" value="REJECT" Text="Reject" Onclick="Button2_Click"></asp:Button></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Approve : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["id"]);
        Label3.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["name"]);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id1=Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
        TransferDAL dalob = new TransferDAL();
        int x = dalob.updateapprove(id1);

        Response.Redirect("View.aspx");
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
        TransferDAL dalob = new TransferDAL();
        int r = dalob.updatereject(id1);
        Response.Redirect("View.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class View : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<TransferBO> List2 = new List<TransferBO>();
            TransferDAL obj1 = new TransferDAL();
            List2 = obj1.view();
            Gridview1.DataSource = List2;
            Gridview1.DataBind();



        }

    }

    protected void Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow SelectedRow = Gridview1.SelectedRow;
        Label id1 = (Label)SelectedRow.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
        int id2 = Convert.ToInt32(id1.Text);
        Label id3 = (Label)SelectedRow.FindControl("Label3") as Label;
        string id4 = Convert.ToString(id3.Text);
        Session["id"] = id2;
        Session["name"] = id4;
        Response.Redirect("Approve.aspx");



    }
}
```